# Batch FOR loop over REG QUERY directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

I am trying to echo a list of each **Registry Key** in the *HKCU* Directory.
In CMD I can run the following command

```
REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\
```

which correctly returns

```
TEMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

However, I am trying to modify the below *FOR* loop which was created to loop over files and folders in a normal Windows Directory structure, But it does not work when working with **Registry Keys**

```
FOR /D %%K in ("%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") DO (
    @echo %%~nxK
)
```

The above loop works fine and outputs all directory names

I tried changing this to

```
FOR /D %%K in ("REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\") DO (
    @echo %%~nxK
)
```

The above does not seem to work.

Also, The **/D** parameter Provided in the *FOR* Loop is apparently *syntax-FOR-Folders*, However I am not sure what a Registry Key would be recognised as.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean extract the path like that :

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\') DO @echo "%%b"
Pause
```

Comment: `FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\') DO @echo "%%b"` as a path could contain spaces...

Comment: @JosefZ Good Catch ;) I edit my post and i change it to yours

Comment: @Hackoo Yes this answer is nearly correct, however I tried changing **tokens=2** to **tokens=3** **@echo "%%a %%b %%c"** and I can only get it to echo out **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp**, I would like to be able to replicate the above in my opening post and output **TEMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp**, preferably 1 part per variable like **a=TEMP, b=REG_EXPAND_SZ** etc...

Comment: @realityStruck `FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\') DO @echo "%%a" "%%b" "%%c"`